# Where is flock() for Perl on Windows?

Tags: perl, fcntl, flock

I have a Perl script that I'd like to run on Windows, using either [Strawberry Perl](http://www.strawberry.com) or [ActivePerl](http://www.activestate.com); I don't care which. This script however, uses `flock()` calls, which does not seem to be included in either of those versions of Perl.

Can anyone help get this up and running?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Is the Fcntl module installed?  Try this:

```
perl.exe -MFcntl -e 1
```

If it complains, you don't have the Fcntl module installed.  If it doesn't complain, then you have access to Fcntl::flock, so put this in your script:

```
use Fcntl qw(:DEFAULT :flock);
```

and off you go.

Answer (score 1):

Try using perldoc -f flock to check the things are supported & then look into the given example to know the usage criteria of the function. Here copied from the perldoc:

C:>perldoc -f flock

```
 use Fcntl ':flock'; # import LOCK_* constant

 sub lock {
     flock(MBOX,LOCK_EX);
     # and, in case someone appended
     # while we were waiting...
     seek(MBOX, 0, 2);
 }

 sub unlock {
     flock(MBOX,LOCK_UN);
 }

 open(MBOX, ">>/usr/spool/mail/$ENV{'USER'}")
```